# SSML for setting exact voice duration

Tags: text-to-speech, amazon-polly, ssml

I'm trying to write an ssml tag-based text that I want to send to my Amazon Polly account using API . API is working fine and I'm getting responses. Here are the ssml tags provided in the [Amazon website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supportedtags.html) .

I want to set a custom duration for each sentence(I mean for example I want each sentence to get read in exactly 7s I mean if we have 3 questions and 3 corresponding answers , whe should have 7*6 s duration file. But the options provided in ssml that are related , are just **maximum duration** or **breaks** or **speech rate**

I tried something but it seems doesnt work fine . I tried to mix break and maximum duration:

```
        <speak>
        <prosody amazon:max-duration="7s">
            What is the capital of France?
            <break time="7s"/>
        </prosody>
        <prosody amazon:max-duration="7s">
            The capital of France is Paris.
            <break time="7s"/>
        </prosody>
        <prosody amazon:max-duration="7s">
            What is the largest ocean?
            <break time="7s"/>
        </prosody>
        <prosody amazon:max-duration="7s">
            The largest ocean is the Pacific Ocean.
            <break time="7s"/>
        </prosody>
        <prosody amazon:max-duration="7s">
             Who wrote Hamlet?
            <break time="7s"/>
        </prosody>
        <prosody amazon:max-duration="7s">
            Hamlet was written by William Shakespeare.
            <break time="7s"/>
        </prosody>
```

another thing is the questions will be changed during time , so if it was just these 3 questions , I would try to fix that manualy but the whole process must be automated.

So for clarity , I want to set **exact duration** of each sentence to be 7s but it is now **maximum duration**=7

What to do?